# Apart from @2x, what other tags are supported by UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I know I can use the `@2x` tag to automatically load images for Retina screens. What other tags are supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently three supported tags:

- `@2x` for Retina screens.
- `~iPad` for iPad, has to be the last tag before the extension.
- `~iPhone` for iPhone and iPod Touch, again, has to be the last.

For the splash screen there’s also the `Default-568h@2x` version for iPhone 5. This suggests that you can use `-568h` to automatically load images for iPhone 5, but that’s unfortunately not the case ([rdar://12516489](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2161402)). You can patch the `UIImage` class to add the support yourself.

In the end there are five possible image variants:

- `Image.png` for older devices, 480✕320
- `Image@2x.png` for Retina, 960✕640
- `Image-568h@2x.png` for Retina, 1136✕640, only after patching `UIImage`
- `Image~iPad.png` for older iPads, 1024✕768
- `Image@2x~iPad.png` for Retina iPad, 2048✕1536

All this is showcased in [iOS Image Loader sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/zoul/iOS-Image-Loader).

Comment: Don't forget ~iPhone for iPhone/iPod touch. Of course there is also -Landscape and -Portrait for the Default.png images.

Comment: ('@' is problematic in SO comments..) I haven't tried your patched UIImage but I did briefly look at the code.  I don't understand why it searches the image name for @ 2x.  The typical usage is to supply the image name sans "@ 2x" and have it load any available @ 2x images when the screen scale is 2.0.  Shouldn't the code just detect that it is on a device with a 568-point tall @ 2x screen then look for images with the -568h@ 2x moniker, for png (if no extension provided) or of any provided file type?  Also, I think your version doesn't handle non-png -568 @ 2x images at all - correct?

Comment: The code was taken from [this blog post](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/20-iPhone5-568h-image-loading) (as credited in the header). Other file formats than PNG are not supported, that’s correct. I had JPEG support there for a second, but then realized I don’t need it anyway. And I think you’re also correct about the rest – I’ll probably update the code tomorrow. It works now, but it appears to be overly complex. Thanks!

Comment: I have simplified the image loading code, it should be trivial to adapt if somebody needs JPEG support or runs into other issues.